# How to pass target name to list of sub-makefiles?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a setup like this:

```
/Makefile
/foo/Makefile
/foo/bar/Makefile
/foo/baz/Makefile
```

The top-level Makefile contains a task which calls the `/foo/Makefile`. This Makefiles creates a list of makefiles in the subdirectories (`bar`, `baz` in the example). For each subdir, it calls the Makefiles:

```
$(SUB_DIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

Which is fine for, say, the `all` task. But if I want to do something else, I get stuck. **Is there a possibility to pass the target to the list of sub-makefiles?** For example:

```
$(SUB_DIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ <task>

clean: $(SUB_DIRS)-clean # or something?
```

Or is my whole concept wrong?

Comment: I've done things like this, but I'm also interested in other solutions to this problem

Comment: You couldn't have "done things like this", as there is no solution. My example is not working at all.

Comment: What version of make are you using, I do exactly this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could simply use the [`MAKECMDGOALS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html) variable:

> Make will set the special variable `MAKECMDGOALS` to the list of goals you specified on the command line. If no goals were given on the command line, this variable is empty.

```
$(SUB_DIRS):
    +$(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```

The `+` sign is important so the underlying [job server](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Job-Slots.html) also handles the recursive make calls with the right amount of threads/core.

---

You can also use the `$(foreach )` function like this:

```
clean:
    $(foreach DIR, $(SUB_DIRS), $(MAKE) -C $(DIR) $@;)
```

Do note as @musicmatze mentionned in the comments that Make flags (like `-j`) won't be passed to the sub-make processes correctly here.

Comment: For the record: This (the `MAKECMDGOALS` one) is the cleanest solution. My solution works as well. The `foreach` approach does work, but if you want to do `make -j 4` (for example) the `foreach` approach does not scale, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

I finally got it work. The approach is:

```
SUB_DIRS        = $(wildcard */.)
SUB_DIRS_ALL    = $(SUB_DIRS:%=all-%)
SUB_DIRS_TEST   = $(SUB_DIRS:%=test-%)
SUB_DIRS_CLEAN  = $(SUB_DIRS:%=clean-%)

#
# Standard task
#
all: $(SUB_DIRS_ALL)

test_uml: $(SUB_DIRS_TEST)

clean: $(SUB_DIRS_CLEAN)

$(SUB_DIRS_ALL):
        @$(MAKE) $(MAKE_FLAGS) -C $(@:all-%=%)

$(SUB_DIRS_TEST):
        @$(MAKE) $(MAKE_FLAGS) -C $(@:test-%=%) test

$(SUB_DIRS_CLEAN):
        @$(MAKE) $(MAKE_FLAGS) -C $(@:clean-%=%) clean
```

I found this solution here: http://lackof.org/taggart/hacking/make-example/

Comment: And this is basically the same thing I posted, just extrapolated out further for when you can't use the directory name itself. (you need to prefix/suffix it and then strip the prefix/suffix at execution time) .  I often do almost exactly as you described, and didn't want to post it verbatim because I was hoping someone would present something I hadn't yet discovered like MAKECMDGOALS to truly solve the problem, and I didn't personally see the value in it beyond what I had already described.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you simply do it as specified, the fun comes in handling at the next level when you may want to both do something and also potentially recurse again.

for example i have a recursive installation like this:

```
$(INSTALL_DIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ install
```